# Firefox 63 Webkit CSS issue using device pixel ratio media query

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, webkit

So I was creating a webpage which worked pretty well. But recently Firefox relseased version 63 and I am having issues with styling of my page. The problem is with the media query -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio.

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar">
  <!-- Navbar for desktop -->
 <div class="nav-buttons">
  <button type="button" name="button" class="icon-logo"></button>
  <button type="button" name="button" class="page-link active">Product</button>
  <button type="button" name="button" class="page-link">User resources</button>
  <button type="button" name="button" class="page-link">Blog</button>
 </div>
 <div class="app-buttons">
    <button type="button" name="button" class="apple"></button>
    <button type="button" name="button" class="google"></button>
    <span>or</span>
    <button type="button" name="button" class="webapp">Sign up/log in</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #92278f; }
```

Giving History to my problem, I was developing this page on Firefox so I didn't really need to use this media query, but when I check this page on chrome my fixed navbar on top had styling issues. I checked on internet if I could use some way of specifically apply css rules to chrome only. I found out that -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0 condition would allow me to do that and coincidentally also work on safari where I found that same issue was showing.

**Works fine** (upto firefox version 62)

[image: Should work like this]

**Original issue with chrome** (link positions)

[image]

**Solved with media query Hack**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)  {
  .navbar .app-buttons button.apple, .navbar .app-buttons button.google {
    top: 4px;
  }
  .navbar .app-buttons button {
    top: -8px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  }
  .navbar .nav-buttons button.page-link {
    top: -7px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  }
}
```

But now after updating Firefox to version 63, I see that this solution is bringing more issue. I read at mozilla link that -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio is not a reliable media query and not supported everytime. I will like to understand what is happening, If there is a solution where I won't need to use such hacks or is there a hacky solution which will solve my problem for now.

**Lately getting issue with Firefox 63**

[image]

Comment: Yeah Firefox 63 shipped with support for that WebKit-specific media feature because other websites were relying on it alone and paying no heed to Firefox. I'm sorry that those other cargo cult sites have ruined it for folks like you.

Comment: I am thinking of recreating this navbar on chrome and see if it works on all versions of firefox, would that be a good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't use `display: flex` for classes `app-buttons` or `nav-buttons` and because of that all the children buttons were rendering differently across different browsers. I have fixed this issue by using flex styling and now I am not using any hacky fixes to render proper styling.

Answer (score 0):

try applying some heights:

```
.navbar,
.navbar .app-buttons button,
.navbar .nav-buttons button.page-link
{
/* include this css for example */
   height: 1.5em;  
}

.navbar .app-buttons button,
.navbar .nav-buttons button.page-link
{
/* include this css for example */
   line-height: 1.5em;  
   align-self:center;
}
```

remove your hacks, see how it goes.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any difference!